# C++ Windows - fill password field of system("run as")

Tags: c++, runas

I know there are many other ways to do this but I want to know how to fill in the password question of the windows the **run as** command automatically.

```
system("runas /user:\"benedikt\" \"xy.exe\"");
```

is there any way to do this? I googled a long time but i only found a lot of tools doing wat I want to do and not a way to do this for myself.
PS: I do not want to use any .Net functions.

Comment: See [Why doesn't the RunAs program accept a password on the command line?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/11/29/271551.aspx).

Comment: @Christian.K A link to that page with a short description of its content would be a good answer according to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I'm going out on a limb here, because I'm not 100% sure that there isn't some (convoluted) way to achieve what you are looking for using stock `runas`.  However, [Why doesn't the RunAs program accept a password on the command line?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/11/29/271551.aspx), suggests there isn't - deliberately so to prevent "security issues" with plain-text passwords in command lines, batch files and tools that can view a command line (like Process Explorer).

BTW, a simple `echo <password> | runas /user:<user> <command>` doesn't seem to work either (it skips over the prompt for the password, but the password itself is not read by `runas` it seems).

So I guess you have to resort to some other means, like using the real API behind it all: [`CreateProcessWithLogin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: the msdn link doesn't work. did you mean [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682431(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: I agree. I would look at writing a small 10 to 20 line console program that stuffs the parameters into CreateProcessWithLogin. For extra credit encrypt the password in some way.

Comment: Hmm. The msdn link did not work for me either.. Here is one that worked with an example code. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: BTW: The example code for CreateProcessWithLoginW appears to solve this problem. It takes a username password and command to run.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I will take a look at this. I hope my limited c++ knowledge is enough for this.

Comment: If you have a access to Visual Studio (even a free express version) compiling that application should not be that hard.

Comment: @default indeed I must have goofed when copy/pasting it. Thanks.

Comment: ok. createProcessWithLogonW works.
My next problem is to run it with local administrator permissions ... windows 7. a elevated process.